# how to read a dir containing sub-dirs using spark's textFile()

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using spark's textFile to read files from hdfs.

the dirs in hdfs looks like:

```
/user/root/kjyw.txt
/user/root/vjwy.txt
/user/root/byeq.txt
/user/root/dira/xxx.txt
```

when I use `sc.textFile("/user/root/")`

the job will fail because the dir contains sub-dirs

how to let spark only read files in the dir?

please do not let me use sc.textFile("/user/root/*.txt") because the files' name is not all end with .txt

Answer (score 0):

```
 val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("/user/root/*/*")
```

Put /* as many directory level as you have. Above will work for the directory structure you have shown.

It will give Pair RDD.